# The swap trick, stl

Tags: c++, vector, stl, swap, c++98

Condsider we have a `std::vector` and want to compose it, make its size == capacity.

```
  vector<int> V;
  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
        V.push_back(i);
  }
  std::cout<<V.size()<<" "<<V.capacity()<<endl;
```

So the output for this is **10 13** (tho its implementation defined, I used VS2017).

How to reallocate vector the way, in which size == capacity?

Comment: There is no guarantee that you *can* shrink a vector. Anything relying on such a "trick" is liable to not work on some platforms

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 there is a `shrink_to_fit()` method for `std::vector`. I'd recommend using that rather than swap trick. However note that `shrink_to_fit()` is a request that
may not be honored by the library implementation.

> It is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). It depends
>   on the implementation whether the request is fulfilled.

For more detail, see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/shrink_to_fit

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am talking about C++98 here :)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a trick described in Scott Meyers's Effective STL book.
The trick is called shrink-to-fit, or how the author calls it, **The swap trick**.

```
 std::vector<int>(V).swap(V);
```

The idea is very simple, we create a temporary copy of V for which size==capacity and swat it with actual V. That easy and simple.

```
  vector<int> V;
  for(int i=0; i<10; ++i)
  {
        V.push_back(i);
  }
  std::cout<<V.size()<<" "<<V.capacity()<<endl;

  std::vector<int>(V).swap(V);

  std::cout<<V.size()<<" "<<V.capacity()<<endl;
```

Now the output for this code is:
**10 13**
**10 10**

> Note: This trick applies also for `std::string and std::deque`

Comment: There is a `shrink_to_fit` method since c++11. No tricks required.

Comment: This book was written for C++98 Standard, but thanks anyway @interjay

Comment: While it is a common implementation approach, I don't believe the standard guarantees that vector's copy constructor results in size == capacity.

Comment: @interjay shrink_to_fit does not guarantee a shrink in capacity.

Comment: @Yiğit True, but implementations are also allowed to reserve more memory than needed when using the swap trick.